# how to get its own view controller inside itself?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, delegates, cs193p

```
@interface RecentPhotosViewController () <PhotoViewControllerDelegate>

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [[self.tabBarController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:1] setDelegate:self];
}
```

The RecentPhotosViewController is a tableviewcontroller which implements a delegate.

I want to set self(RecentPhotosViewController) as the delegate in vieDidLoad(), but when i tried to type:self.setDelegate it turned out self doesn't have this setDelegate method, then i tried this:[[self.tabBarController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:1] setDelegate:self];(this tableview is one of the viewcontrollers of the tabBarControllers.

Then i got an error:[RecentPhotosViewController setDelegate:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xc939960. I don't know how to fix this.

Comment: Tried `parentViewController`?

Comment: Just tried parentViewController, but still couldn't call the setDelegate method. Why? Couldn't a viewcontroller call setDelegate method? Weird cause i saw u can call it in a prepareforsegue using:segue.destinationViewController setDelegate.

Comment: But what class is the object of which you want to self as delegate of?

Comment: It's just the RecentPhotosViewController which is a talbeviewcontroller.

Comment: But you want to set self.delegate = self?

Comment: yep.....................

Comment: Then you have to declare a @property and synthesize it.

Answer (score 0):

Do this:

```
@interface RecentPhotosViewController

//etc.

@property (nonatomic, assign) id delegate;

@end

@implementation RecentPhotosViewController

// etc.

@synthesize delegate;

@end
```

Comment: ..... I already did that in the delegator. I just couldn't set myself as the delegate.